# Why does product cannot be added on cart when put in live?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to follow a tutorial on php, yet I am trying to learn this language. The shopping cart tutorial when on my localhost the add to cart function works fine, but when I tried to put on live it doesn't works anymore.

Below is the php(basket) file which is responsible for adding, removing, editing cart.

```
...
session_start();
$jim = new Shopping();
$p = $_GET['p'];
if(!is set($_SESSION['cart'])){
      $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
      $_SESSION['proID'] = 0;
}
if($p == 'addtocart'){
       $product = $_POST['product'];
       $price = $_POST['price'];
       $qty = $_POST['qty'];
       $jim->addtocart($product, $price, $qty);
}...
class Shopping{
        function addtocart($product, $price, $qty){
               $cart = array(
                    'proID' => $_SESSION['proID'],
                    'product' => $product,
                    'price' => $price,
                    'qty' => $qty
               );
               $_SESSION['proID'] = $_SESSION['proID'] +1;
               array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$cart);

               return true;
          }
     ...
```

This is the jquery that calls the id from productDetails page:

```
$(function()){
         $('#add-to-cart').on('click',function(){
              $(this).siblings('info').fadeIn(700).fadeOut(1000);
               var price = $(this).siblings('p').children('.price').html();
               var product = $(this).siblings('.product').html();
               $.post('cart/basket.php?p=addtocart',
                           {
                                   price:price,
                                   product: product,
                                   qty:1;
                           }
                 );
         });
...
```

This is the page for cart

```
 ...
 <?php if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){ ?>
     <?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $row): ?>
            ...//show item, price, qty, total
     <?php end foreach; ?>
           ...//show sub total, vat, grand total
  <?php } else { ?>
           //Message showing cart is empty.
  <?php } ?>
  ...
```

What i cannot understand is when I put on free hosting site, after clicking the "Add to Cart" button it prompt that product is added to cart. But when I visited the cart page, there is no item on it, it returns to else statement of the cart page. If I am on my PC, it works.

**Any help is much appreciated.**

Comment: use echo var_dump($_REQUEST) to check if the values get stored in the Session, if not, check your php.ini. Maybe the free Hoster does not allow to store values in that via the php.ini

Comment: I'd check whether the session has been started. `var_dump( session_start() );` as well.

Comment: does your cart page have a `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes, there is session _start() on it. It is put on header.php file which was called/included on cart.php

Comment: I tried echoing var_dump($_REQUEST) on cart.php and it result to "array(0){}", what to do with php.ini?

Comment: Echoing var_dump(session_start()); the page says that a session had already been started. And it ignores, where I declared the session_start().